# RegEx to integrate Fogbugz with TeamCity

Tags: regex, teamcity, fogbugz

I'm trying to integrate Fogbugz issue tracking with TeamCity and I'm struggling to get the regex correct. We usually mark the case in the check in comment like "BugzID: 1234" but I'd like to get a regex that doesn't care about capitalization, or if the ":" is there. There can also be text before or after the bugzid.

I tried to use:
\b(?(review|case|bug[zs]?(\s| )*(id)?:?)s?(\s| )*([#:; ]| )+)((([ ,:;#]|and)*)(?\d+))+

which I got from:
help.fogcreek.com/7772/link-fogbugz-cases-to-changesetscommits-in-kiln

but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. The link it generates has "BugzID:" for the ID, which should be "1234".

Can any regex experts help?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give us a list of potential matches so we understand your input. Examples are better than words.

Comment: Examples: "PUB - BugzID: 1234 - Fixed null reference", "INTERNAL - bugzid 2222 - added text box", "bugzid: 54321 - speed improvements to processing"

Comment: Working on it. You just want to match the ID?

Answer (score 0):

To match the ID only:

**Option 1 (Perl, PHP, Ruby 2+)**

```
(?i)bugzid:? \K\d+
```

**Option 2 (Java, .NET)**

```
(?i)(?<=bugzid:? )\d+
```

**Option 3 (Other Engines)**

```
/bugzid:? (\d+)/i
```

The ID is captured to Group 1. The way to set case-insensitivity in JS is shown, it will differ in some engines.